# How to write config.yml for Netlify CMS to automate blog entries into a `posts` folder in a Gatsby project?

Tags: node.js, gatsby, netlify-cms

I'm unable to figure out how to write the Netlify CMS config.yml for a `posts` folder that looks like [image: folder structure]

The structure is inspired by the [Gatsby Personal Blog Starter](https://gatsby-starter-personal-blog.greglobinski.com).
My blog content looks like https://ibb.co/cxXL9MJ:

This is my current [config.yml](https://github.com/divyamrastogi/Javascript-Bit/blob/38297c2792e37603df20ea22da42f35f49e6d586/static/admin/config.yml), [gatsby-config.js](https://github.com/divyamrastogi/Javascript-Bit/blob/38297c2792e37603df20ea22da42f35f49e6d586/gatsby-config.js) and [gatsby-node.js](https://github.com/divyamrastogi/Javascript-Bit/blob/38297c2792e37603df20ea22da42f35f49e6d586/gatsby-node.js).

You can browse the whole [branch](https://github.com/divyamrastogi/Javascript-Bit/tree/38297c2792e37603df20ea22da42f35f49e6d586) for more details.

Comment: hhmm, just a guess here, maybe netlifyCMS doesn't understand the nested folder structure. Could you convert those folder into just file, i.e `2019-01-10-blog-name/index.md` to `2019-01-10-blog-name.md` and try to see if it loads up into the CMS?

Comment: @DerekNguyen: You're right. It works but then I got stuck again because the cover photo wouldn't render. I kept getting an error while running `gatsby build` in my `layouts.js` which said that my cover image could not have children because it was a string.

After that, I found this [blog](https://theleakycauldronblog.com/blog/problems-with-gatsby-image-and-their-workarounds/) which helped me a lot. It fixed the error, but I couldn't get my cover image to render. It just wasn't in my DOM. After that, I just gave up.

Comment: sorry to hear that, gatsby could definitely be too much sometimes. If you would share your new error here or create a new thread, I'm sure someone could help you out -- or join the [official discord server here](https://discord.gg/ZjUnzy) and the [official spectrum forum here](https://spectrum.chat/gatsby-js)